# NullReferenceException was unhandled when opening a connection

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm getting an error in this code that says: *object reference not set to an instance of an object*.

```
Private Sub frmAdd_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    con.ConnectionString = strcon

    con.Open()

con.ConnectionString = strcon
```

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That means that you are using a variable that is null (it's not set to point to an instance of any object).  In this case, `con` must be null, so you need to check if it's null, and if so, then set it to a new object.  For instance:

```
If con Is Nothing Then
    con = New OleDbConnection()  ' Or whatever type it is...
End If
con.ConnectionString = strcon
con.Open()
```

Or, better yet, just set it to a new object when you declare the variable, if that's appropriate, for instance:

```
Dim conn As New OleDbConnection()
```

However, as Tim pointed out, it's best to create a new connection each time you need one, and then you can use a `Using` block which will properly dispose of the object every time:

```
Using con As New OleDbConnection(strcon)
    con.Open()
    ' Use the connection ...
End Using
```

Comment: con is my connection. i have it initialized as:

Dim con as OleDbConnection

Comment: That doesn't create an object, that just declares a variable (which may or may not point to an object).

Comment: Thank you Steven for the answer

Comment: No problem.  For more info, check out my answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11934941/why-is-new-constructor-used-sometimes-but-not-others-basic-oop-understanding/11935822#11935822  You may find that informative.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you get that error because the connection is yet not initialized. But instead of using a field i would suggest to create a local variable because you should always close connections as soon as possible best by using `Using`-statement. So create a connection where you need it and not *globally*.

So this would fix it(but is not recommended):

```
Private Sub frmAdd_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    con = new SqlConnection(strcon)
    con.Open() ' <-- don't do that with connection pooling
```

Comment: I have it initialized outside the sub. This is what i used to initialized the connection


Dim strcon = ("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source = " & System.Environment.CurrentDirectory & "\Supplies.mdb")

Comment: @RaraArar You've initialised `strcon`. You haven't initialised `con`.